# Building multiple binaries with go

Tags: go, compilation

My project is structured as so:

```
src/github.com/foo/bar/
   - binary1
      - binary1.go
   - binary2
      - binary2.go
```

Each of these binaries are in a package `main`.

Is there a way, when I'm in the directory `src/github.com/foo/bar` to just run `go build` and end up with both binaries compiled?

`go build ./...` didn't produce any binaries.
`go build -a` actually builds every package.

Or should I just call it as :

```
(cd binary1; go build)
(cd binary2; go build)
```

Comment: `go install ./...`

Comment: `go install` will move everything to $GOPATH/bin 

Is this idiomatic? It seems a bit odd to me to have all my different project's binaries sit in the same `bin` directory.

Comment: Yes, that's to usual place to handle binaries. You can use the GOBIN env variable if you want: `GOBIN=$PWD go install ./...`

Comment: I guess it seems a bit odd to me because I'd like my project's binaries to be self-contained and not mixed in with other binaries. What if there's naming collisions? It's also frustrating to have to set GOBIN every time I work on a project, so I can keep my binaries separated. Any thoughts?

Comment: Most projects that require more than the basic functionality provided by the `go` commands use a makefile or shell script to do what they want.